# Express elements of a matrix with the correct mathematical symbolism

Tags: matrices

I have matrices $A \in \mathbb{N}^{n \times n}$, with $n \geq 3$, of the following type (illustrated for $n=5$):

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ 
10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\ 
15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19\\ 
20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24
\end{pmatrix}

The elements of the matrix are $$a_{0,0} = 0, \quad a_{0,1} = 1, \quad \cdots \quad \quad a_{4,4} = 24.$$

I am looking for a general, elegant and compact way of expressing the elements of this matrix.

Comment: How about $a_{i,j} = ni + j$?

Answer (score 2):

Would something along these lines work for you?

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & \dots & n - 1\\
n & n + 1 & \dots & 2n-1\\
2n & 2n + 1 & \dots & 3n-1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
(n-1)n & (n-1)n + 1 & \dots & (n)n - 1
\end{pmatrix}